# Numbering elements in a vector

Tags: r

I would like to number the elements of a vector, assigning '1' to the smallest element in the vector.  I know how to do this, but my solution (code included below) seems overly complex.  Is there a much simpler solution?

In my example below there are 5 unique numbers in the vector 'data'.  The number 3 is the smallest and should be assigned the number '1'; the number 100 is the largest and should be assigned the number '5'.

The desired solution for the vector 'data' is: `c(2,3,4,4,3,1,5)`.

```
data <- c(5,8,12,12,8,3,100)
unique.numbers <- sort(unique(data))
numbering <- seq(1:length(unique(data)))
template <- cbind(numbering,unique.numbers)
output <- rep(NA, length(data))
for(i in 1:length(data)) { 
  for(j in 1:dim(template)[1]) { 
      if(data[i]==template[j,2]) output[i]=j 
  }
}
output
```

Thank you for any advice.  I am trying to become more efficient with my programming.

Mark Miller

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More compact version of your program.

```
dat <- c(5,8,12,12,8,3,100)
dat_sorted <- sort(unique(dat))
match(dat,dat_sorted)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using numeric or integer data you can use `as.numeric(factor())`

```
dat <- c(5,8,12,12,8,3,100)
as.numeric(factor(dat))
```

Also, as a side note, you should avoid using `data` as a variable name in `R` since its already a built-in function.

Comment: Important correction (see the R FAQ 7.10) :  `as.numeric(as.character(factor(dat)))`  or you will be sad.

Comment: The side note is wrong, `data` is *not* a variable name in R, it is a function name and there is a big difference in that.

Comment: @SimonUrbanek that's what I tried to say. Sorry for the confusion.  CarlWitthof, good point. Wojciech's answer above is a much better option.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is:

```
> rank(data)
[1] 2.0 3.5 5.5 5.5 3.5 1.0 7.0
```

You can see the argument "ties.method" for how to handle ties.

Comment: I don't believe any of the "ties.method"s give the desired outcome though.

Comment: @Dason agreed. But (1) I'm not sure user1184072 is married to his form of output and (2) if he is, it might be a better place to start from.